# count++ : While() wont stop loop after count reached

Tags: java, loops, netbeans, while-loop

been beating my head against the wall here... might have something to do with the late hour, but my while loop will not end once i have entered my variable "count" for the third time. Code as follows:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        final String CORRECT_PASSWORD = "CS1160";
        String password;
        int count = 0;

       //ask for password

        System.out.println("Please enter your password: ");      
        password = input.nextLine();

        if(password.equals(CORRECT_PASSWORD)){
           System.out.println("You have successfully logged in.");
                                             }

       count = 0;
    while(count < 3){
        while(!password.equals(CORRECT_PASSWORD))
         {
           System.out.println("Incorrect Password Entered.");
           System.out.println("Please enter your password: ");
           password=input.nextLine();
           count++;

        if(password.equals(CORRECT_PASSWORD)){
           System.out.println("You have successfully logged in.");

           count++;   
         }}



        }
        System.out.println("You have been locked out.");
        }}
```

___________________END_______________________

- Everything compiles fine... looks to be solid from my understanding of while loops, just for some reason it will not stop looping once "Count" reaches three.
  Is there perhaps something I am overlooking?

Thanks so much
-Sam

Answer (score 1):

Don't nest the loops, use a boolean and condition and one loop. Something like,

```
while(count < 3 && !password.equals(CORRECT_PASSWORD))
```

Comment: For further explanation, the inner loop will continue to run until the correct password is entered. So even though `count` may be incremented well above 3, the outer loop never completes an iteration until the correct password is entered and the inner loop is allowed to terminate.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the inner while loop. Until you don't give the right password it, won't come out of there. Use single while loop, something like:

```
while(count < 3 && !password.equals(CORRECT_PASSWORD))
```

Then inside this, you should write:

```
System.out.println("Please enter your password: ");
           password=input.nextLine();
           count++;

        if(password.equals(CORRECT_PASSWORD)){
           System.out.println("You have successfully logged in.");
           break;//brings you out of the while loop as you don't need to check for the password again.
         }

           count++;
```